# How to connect streaming data and display in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-embedded

I am working on a power bi report which is embedded in a portal. I need to display live GPS live locations of vehicles in a MAP based on a company that user has access to in the portal. basically every user will have a company associated to them and I'll use rowlevelsecurity for doing this.

A third party application will give access to live streaming data through a API. Is it possible to connect to a third party application API from power bi and show gps locations? If it is possible, how can I do it? I am totally new to this. please help me with any documents/scripts. We have power bi pro license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case you will not be able to do it all in Power BI, you'll need to push the streaming data to some sort of database, Azure SQL Server/Azure Cosmos DB/Azure Databricks using Event Hubs and maybe Streaming Analytics as well. So for example your stream sends the data to the event hub endpoint, then sends it to a database, then Power BI reads it.

You can then link a Power BI report to that database and set it up in Direct Query mode, and then set the [page refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh#automatic-page-refresh-in-the-power-bi-service) on the report. Depending on the type of service your period of refresh for none Embedded/Premium workspaces will be 30mins or more, and not 'realtime'